# difference of artifactId and name in maven POM

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am new to maven and I'm confused about the difference between the `artifactId` and `name`.

What I know is that `artifactId` is the name of the artifact you are creating. I know that `artifactId` together with the `groupId` is use to uniquely identifies an artifact. So what is `<name>` purpose in POM. like the pom below I got from a site there is an `artifactId` and at the same time a `<name>`.

```
<groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multi</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Multi Chapter Simple Parent Project</name>
```

Answer (score 29):

You are correct that the `artifactId` helps identify the project.

The `name` is simply a human-readable "friendly" name. It is not required for a basic setup.

From the [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Basics),

> **artifactId**: The artifactId is generally the name that the project is known by. Although the groupId is important, people within the group will rarely mention the groupId in discussion ... It, along with the groupId, create a key that separates this project from every other project in the world (at least, it should :) ). Along with the groupId, the artifactId fully defines the artifact's living quarters within the repository.

Comment: Note Maven will sometimes print the name for you to identify the module, e.g. when building a multi-module project I see the build results next to each module's name.

Answer (score 20):

The `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` form a composite unique identifier (or [coordinate](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates)) for this project.  Each of these values has a fairly rigid naming convention that allows well organized groups, artifacts and versions.

The `name` is simply a readable name for the project and does not need to be unique or comply to the same conventions (so it can contain spaces and other characters).

Comment: +1  - I hate documentation that simply says what it is: Artifact ID is an ID that identifies the Artifact.  Much better is why? Why is there an Artifact ID? Why did the team create it created?   What problem occurred, and how did Artifact ID become a solution?

Answer (score 3):

The name is used for the project used by maven to build the artifact, while the artifact-id is used to identify the artifact that will be built.

For example:

This pom file definition for the rsts ear file:

[image]

Causes the rsts-ear project to be imported into Eclipse:

[image]

But creates the rsts_ear artifact in the nexus:

[image]

This means that the artifact-id, not the name, is referenced to include the artifact in the build as part of another artifact.

[image]